# Changing sales order quotation preview page in odoo 12

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

I am trying to make changes in the preview page for sales order quotations. I need to replace the "powered by odoo logo" from the page with something else.Here is the screenshot of the page. [image: Image with the logo]

I tried to find the page in sale and associated modules in the addons folder.
Tried **grep -rnw '/path/to/addons/' -e 'Odoo Logo'** to find a view, but commenting the lines in the view did't do anything.How is this preview page created? How do i make change in this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the QWeb template with ID "portal_record_sidebar". You can find that in the portal app.

There are a lot of examples in Odoo code how to extend/change QWeb client templates.

Following is a random example from [Odoo module website_sale](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/ae48324aee47aa4851e313671241970a5b8528b5/addons/website_sale/views/templates.xml#L1633-L1640):

```xml
<template id="website_sale.brand_promotion" inherit_id="website.brand_promotion">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_brand_promotion')]" position="replace">
        <div class="o_brand_promotion">
            Powered by <a target="_blank" class="badge badge-danger" href="http://www.odoo.com/page/website-builder?utm_source=db&amp;utm_medium=website">Odoo</a>,
            the #1 <a target="_blank" href="http://www.odoo.com/page/e-commerce?utm_source=db&amp;utm_medium=website">Open Source eCommerce</a>.
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I even tried some debranding apps, but they seem to install the website app which i don't need.